# Problem with Xsens-MTIG

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte

I downloaded the cyphy_xsens_mtig package.
Built all the dependencies and then
cmake cyphy_xesns_mtig...No error

but when I run the node

sai@sai:~$ rosrun cyphy_xsens_mtig mtig_node
[FATAL] [1346038310.941690009]: MTi -- Unable to connect to the MTi
[FATAL] [1346038310.941830180]: BREAKPOINT HIT
file = /home/sai/fuerte_workspace/cyphy/cyphy_Drivers/cyphy_xsens_mtig/src/mtig_node.cpp
line=64

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Find the link to the code at

http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/doc/api/cyphy_xsens_mtig/html/mtig__node_8cpp_source.html

I have edited the line 55 by changing ttyUSBxsens to ttyUSB0.

I have also connected the xsens mtig to the USB port and it is at ttyUSB0

More importantly, it worked before on ubuntu 10.04 and fuerte but later i changed to ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte with all the same settings ..and now its not working

Please let me know what i should do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42328/problem-with-xsens-mtig/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-08-27**:
I've had similar problems with hardware drivers on Ubuntu 12.04, it seems the new LTS version does not give the user permissions to use open virtual ports. To check if this is your problem you can simply change the permissions on your port, 'sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0' and then try to run the node?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-08-29**:
Thank you Goncalo Cabrita ..it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is not a problem related to ROS, it is in fact a problem with Ubuntu 12.04.

You need to give your user permissions to open virtual com ports (such as for the FTDI on the XSens-MTiG):

$ sudo gedit /etc/group

And then add your username to the uucp group (change username for YOUR username):

uucp:x:10:username

And that's it! Save and close, now whenever you restart you can open any virtual com port without constantly changing the port's permissions.

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1